# NUXT JS: Cannot find module node:fs

Tags: nuxt.js

I get the following error while calling `run npm run dev` on local development

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after I created a new nuxt-app and after I run npm run dev.
my node version was 14.x and there are some new updates in nuxt default packages that are not compatible with this version.
so I changed my nodeJs version to 16.4.1 and the problem solved...